# Downloading binary file using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 - content is binary gibberish

Tags: file, vbscript, download, binary, winhttp

I'm trying to download an MS Excel file (binary). I even get the correct response headers (see both images (httpfox and vbscript)  attached). When trying to save `objWinHttp.ResponseBody` using the following function (found in many posts referring to download binary files):

```
Function SaveBinaryData (FileName, ByteArray)
  adTypeBinary = 1
  adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

  SET BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary

  BinaryStream.Open
  BinaryStream.Write(ByteArray)

  BinaryStream.SaveToFile FileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
  BinaryStream = 0
  'BinaryStream.Close
  'Return SaveBinaryData
End Function
```

the file is being saved as gibberish with binary content.

Here is the Excel file if someone would like to see how the content looks like: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17845471/mySrsExport.xls

Comment: Your XLS file is "gibrished" for me just downloading it normally using your Dropbox link. Just looking at it using a hex editor, it doesn't appear to be a valid Excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your code. Your file just isn't an Excel workbook, as @Bond already pointed out. It's a gzip-compressed HTML page. Save it as `mySrsExport.htm.gz` and you'll be able to extract the HTML file with [`gunzip`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm) or [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or some other (un)packer.

Comment: Thank you so much both - you made my day brighter still don't have enough reputation to vote up - yet, this is the CORRECT answer.! : - )